# Переписать js скрипт по БЭМ

Tags: javascript, jquery, бэм

хочу переписать JS скрипт по методологии БЭМ. Чтобы скрипт можно было переиспользовать.
Но не совсем уверен, как правильно это сделать. Прошу вашей помощи.

```js
(function() {
  var items = '.checkboxes__items';
  var hidden = '.checkboxes__item-hidden';
  var show = 'checkboxes__item';
  var btn_more = '.checkboxes__btn-more';

  $(btn_more).on('click', function() {
    $(items).find(hidden).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass(show);
    });
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  color: #35373b;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkboxes__item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.checkboxes__item-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <div class="checkboxes__title">Title</div>
  <div class="checkboxes__items">
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Education
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Weapon
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Comics
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Something
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Nation
      </span>
    </label>

    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        People
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Future
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        History
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Politic
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Economy
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Activity
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="checkboxes__btn-more">
    + <b>More</b> (<span class="checkboxed__value">Num</span>)
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: какая связь между js и бэм? Чем не устраивает текущий код?

Comment: @Grundy https://ru.bem.info/methodology/js/

Comment: и как ссылка связана с текущим кодом? :)

Comment: не стоит использовать БЭМ в js, плохая практика) сделать "копируемый" компонент можно и без него, соблюдая правила ООП, вдруг вы захотите отказаться от БЭМ, тогда вам придется и переписать все js скрипты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что приходит в голову при разговоре о переиспользовании, это снижение уровня связности. Сейчас ваша функция на js требует полного соответствия структуры в html. Можно создать шаблон для элемента, на который вы будете весить событие и добавить его к указанному DOM элементу. Шаблон может выглядеть так:

```
const myTemplate = `<label class="${element}__item">` +
                   `<input class="${element}__item-hiden">` +
                   ........... // тут спаны по вкусу
                   '</label>';
```

В таком варианте будет достаточно создать один див с классом, а ваша функция добавит все что требуется для структуры.
 Значения чекбоксов можно передавать в опциях при вызове:

```
 valuesList = [
    {caption: 'Первое', value: 1},
    {caption: 'Второе', value: 2},
    {caption: 'Компот', value: 3)]
```

Ка вариант, можно сделать чтобы события автоматически назначались на все элементы страницы с указанным классом:

```
export default class {
  constructor(options = {}) {

    const {element = '.chekboxes', valuesList} = options


    const itemsList = [...document.querySelectorAll(element)]
    itemsList.forEach(item => {

      // Тут можно добавить структуру каждому списку чекбоксов
      // Повесить прослушку нужных событи1

      })
    }
  }
```

Так уже можно указывать свои классы или использовать базовый. Теперь для вызова будем иметь что-то подобное этому:

```
import MyCheckbox from '../path/MyCheckbox.js';

const myCheckbox = new MyCheckbox({
    element: 'my-class',
    valuesList: [
    {caption: 'Первое', value: 1},
    {caption: 'Второе', value: 2},
    {caption: 'Компот', value: 3)
    ]})
```

Обратите внимание на стили... куда же вы потом с пикселями в переиспользование?
Сложите все в одну папку и дайте соответствующие ей имена. Может еще что-то упустил.

P.S. и конечно решить, точно ли нужен jQuery.